# Why can't a "const static double variable" be declared in a class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

For my assignment, I was required to make a const static double variable in a class but my compiler gives an error.

```
const static double long_tarif = 1500.0;//error
const static int long_tarif = 1500;//no error

IntelliSense: a member of type "const double" cannot have an in-class 
initializer
```

I'm working on visual studio 2013.

Comment: It can, it just can't be initialized in the class.

Comment: The error message just says it. The problem is not the declaration but the initialization. The case of the `int` is an exception.

Comment: To enxtend on George's comment, do `struct C { static const double d; };` (header) and `const double C::d = 3.14159;` (source).

Comment: @i160084AhmedBin You should _probably_ initialize it wherever you implement your class. See YSC's comment